# Insert same rows for a different id MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-python

I have 3 tables. Accounts, Brands and Models.

In Brands and Models I have Foreign Key reference to an Account so every account has a number of brands and models.

I want to know how can I copy all rows from Brands for an account id, all rows from Models for the same account id and insert them again in those two tables BUT for different account id.

Should be simple copy/paste but I need an efficient way of doing it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, it's a simple insert with a select statement - you can use a constant in your select statement:

Assuming 88 is the account you're copying from, and 99 is the account you're copying to:

```
insert Brands (AccountID, BrandName, Description, etc...)
  select 99, BrandName, Description, etc...
  from Brands
  where AccountID = 88;
```